# All Ubuntu flavors fail to install, hanging at the very same stage (grub 2 package)

Tags: grub2

*I dont think it's a duplicate as it concerns single boot only setup without Windows. The solution from the other question didn't help anyway.*

I just recently bought a brand new HP 250 G6 laptop without a system and I'm trying to install Ubuntu on it with live USB (single boot, the pc came with just FreeBios on it). I did it before a few times adn never experienced problems. This time, the installation proceeds seemingly smoothly until it reaches the stage when it is installing "grub 2" package. It somewhat freezes.

Well, the prompt registers some actions, but I waited up to 4 hours for the installation bar to progress beyond "installing grub 2 package" to no avail. The last prompts include "searching for a keyring" and "running anachron jobs". I tried two different UBSs and various ISOs (Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Linux Mint xfce) and the installation stalls at the very same stage. Im installing in the UEFI mode, the USB is configured properly. I added the EFI partition and I tried to use both the entire disk and one the partitions as device boot loader. 1 more important detail - after the first failed attempt, the laptop now boots to Grub prompts unless you try to f9/f10 to bios.

Update: Im creating it on my Windows PC with Rufus (fat 32, gptfor uefi mode, iso). Yes, when i choose the try without installing option, I can access the live version without any problem. Indeed, the problem appear during running the installation process, when the bar reaches grub 2 package. I tried with and without access to internet, with and without installing updates during the installation process. Im isntalling in the UEFI mode and I choose UEFI USB as boot source. My disk uses GPT (i run gdisk on the live version in terminal)

Update2: I mean to install Ubuntu only, no Windows. But when I install, the installer asks me if i want to install alongside Ubuntu, which means it somewhat recognizes the previous failed attempt at instllation as actual system. I always pick to erase the contents of the disk and install a new system. Below the commands

```
df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           379M  1.3M  378M   1% /run
/dev/sdb1       7.3G  1.1G  6.3G  14% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      968M  968M     0 100% /rofs
/cow            1.9G   31M  1.9G   2% /
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           379M  8.0K  379M   1% /run/user/999



sudo parted -ls

Model: ATA HGST HTS545050A7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
1      1049kB  4000MB  3999MB  linux-swap(v1)
2      4000MB  24.0GB  20.0GB  ext4
3      24.0GB  124GB   100GB   ext4
4      124GB   125GB   512MB   fat32                 boot, esp


Model: TOSHIBA TransMemory (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 7759MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
1      1049kB  7759MB  7758MB  fat32        Microsoft Basic Data  msftdata


Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/zram1: 992MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
1      0.00B  992MB  992MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/zram0: 992MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
1      0.00B  992MB  992MB  linux-swap(v1)




sudo lsblk -f

Model: ATA HGST HTS545050A7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
1      1049kB  4000MB  3999MB  linux-swap(v1)
2      4000MB  24.0GB  20.0GB  ext4
3      24.0GB  124GB   100GB   ext4
4      124GB   125GB   512MB   fat32                 boot, esp


Model: TOSHIBA TransMemory (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 7759MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
1      1049kB  7759MB  7758MB  fat32        Microsoft Basic Data  msftdata


Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/zram1: 992MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
1      0.00B  992MB  992MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/zram0: 992MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
1      0.00B  992MB  992MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: How do you create your USB boot drive? Which tool/method?  Is the live system (when booted from the USB pendrive) working well? It seems to me that the problem appears, when you run the installer. Is this correct? Are you trying to install in UEFI mode or BIOS mode? Is there an MSDOS partition table (MBR) or a GUID partition table (GPT)?

Comment: Hi, I added information concerning your question to my original post

Comment: Thanks for the updated question. I suspect, that the partition table does not have what is needed to install the bootloader `grub`. Are you installing alongside Windows, alongside another linux distro or will there be only Ubuntu? - Please run the following command lines and post the output in your original question. Indent each line of the output 4 spaces to render it as 'code': `df -h` and `sudo parted -ls` and `sudo lsblk -f`

Comment: Hi @sudodus , I added the output and new information

Comment: If it has installed, but maybe not grub2, post this link. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info It may allow you to install grub in UEFI boot mode if booted in UEFI mode. But HP does not auto boot ubuntu. If only installing Ubuntu one work around is to change the description of Ubuntu/grub UEFI entry to read "Windows Boot Manager". See IV: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Two possible problems

I can see two possible problems from the output of the commands, that you added to your original question. (Others might see other problems; I am rather sure that we can solve your problem with grub.)

1. You have actually booted in BIOS (alias legacy) mode (not in UEFI mode), and your file system should have a small partition with the `bios_grub` flag.
2. The EFI partition is too far away from the head end of the drive, so the UEFI/BIOS system cannot see it and let grub use it.

This link is helpful to understand how to create a partition table,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

### Erase disk and install Lubuntu

If you have a **backup of your personal data** (everything that you cannot afford to lose), I suggest that you test this method.

`zram` makes me think that you are installing Lubuntu.

The easiest way to get a working system is to let the installer create the file system according to this screenshot,

[image]

### Get two `ext4` partitions and make the system use them

If you want two `ext4` partitions, you can do that after the installation:

- boot into the USB install drive again, 'Try Lubuntu'.
- Use gparted to shrink the root partition (with `ext4`), and create a second `ext4` partition, like you show in the edited question). You can use that partition as **home** partition, or if you wish as a **data** partition.

  1. Edit **`fstab`** of the installed system, to mount the partition automatically. But now you should mount it manually, and then

     ```
     sudo nano /mountpoint/etc/fstab
     ```
  2. If you have a backup of your home partition, you can copy it back to this new partition, and maybe you find it easier to make a new installation and to edit the `fstab` file.

     This time you select 'Something else' at the partitioning window and select the partitions, that should be correct and in good order now.

### Solution

After a dialogue (as comments), the OP, @NVI, found this solution:

*I suggested:*

> Since you are not going to have Windows in this drive, you need not
>   have a GUID partition table. I suggest that you use `gparted` and create
>   an MSDOS partition table (default in `gparted` via 'Device -- Create
>   Partition Table'). Then try with the automatic 'erase disk and install
>   lubuntu' option.

*The OP reported the result:*

> I used gparted to create an MSDOS partition and changed my live USB
>   into a MBR for BIOS one and It did work! The installation completed
>   without any problems. You can probably add this solution to your
>   answer **for users that do not plan on installing Windows on the same
>   drive**.

Comment: Yes, the usb that im now trying to boot has lubuntu on it. I tried your solutions - I disabled leagcy mode in bios settings and I tried to partition my disk in a different way - first by placing the efi partition at the beginning, and then by using the automatic 'erase disk and install lubuntu' option, but it still freezes at trying to install the grub 2 package...

Comment: Since you are not going to have Windows in this drive, you need not have a GUID partition table. I suggest that you use `gparted` and create an MSDOS partition table (default in  `gparted` via 'Device -- Create Partition Table'). Then try with the automatic 'erase disk and install lubuntu' option. It should work, if the Lubuntu install drive's operating system is healthy. You can check it according to [Checking the iso file and the boot drive - detailed tips](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13511608#post13511608)

Comment: Another idea is to wipe the first mibibyte of the internal disk in order to remove data, that might confuse the installer. You can use [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) to do that in a safe way.  See the details at this link: [mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe). After that you can use `gparted` again to create a partition table.

Comment: I used gparted to create an MSDOS partition and changed my live UBS into a MDR for BIOS one and It did work! The installation completed without any problems. You can probably add this solution to your answer for users that do not plan on installing Windows on the smae drive.

Comment: Congratulations @NVI, you found a solution :-)

Comment: Final (?) comment: It is still possible to install Windows (10) in BIOS mode in an MSDOS partition table. But it wants primary partitions, while Lubuntu is happy also with a logical partition (so in that case you can make an extended partition and one or more logical partitions in it for Ubuntu, Lubuntu or another Ubuntu flavour).